# Adding permissions to app manifest programmatically

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

I am trying to add permissions to my application manifest, so it can access other apps that the user installs at runtime. I thought the way to do this was to define a permission-tree in the manifest, and then use PackageManager.addPermission() to add permissions under that tree. However, I can't get this to work and the documentation I found wasn't conclusive. Could anybody show me how to do this by means of a simple example?

Comment: After reading your answers, I'm gonna explain further what I'm trying to do. The idea is that my app communicates to some add-on like components. As right know, all these add-ons are known by the app (so no problem with permissions) but the user should be able to install new add-ons through a special activity: I see a list of available apps, I choose one and it gets installed. So then, this new add-on should appear in a menu of my main app and it should be possible to interact with it. I've already seen similar things, but I understand it is a complicated subject.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to other applications only to your application and to the applications running with your application's user ID.

Comment: Well, don't really know what you mean but it is possible to have access to components of other applications - even when they have different ID. It's all explained in the Android Security Framework.

Comment: @androidtje: You can't change anything outside of your own application. Please point me to the documentation part which describes the opposite.

Comment: The idea is not to change anything outside my app. I just want to grant my app the necessary permissions to interact with a 3rd party app, if the latter offers that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible in a non rooted device. Security issues involved.

Comment: Yes, I know a rooted device would make it possible. But what about signature permissions? I thought Android's Security Framework allowed to define the right environment so that only those applications that you want would have access to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Only rooted devices are cable of that, due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think this was possible. I thought (and was thought by a lecturer, who could also be wrong) that all the permissions had to be added as the code compiles. If you can add permissions afterwards, wouldn't that allow apps to access all of my information without my permission? There would also be no point in the confirmation screen when downloading an app, as the permissions it warns you about may not all f the permissions it is going to use.

In my opinion I don't think it should be possible. It is too easily abused. I also don't think it is possible and I think you will have a hard time finding any info on it.